# FFT freq wrong is there a problem in code

Tags: python-3.x, fft

Want to convert raw accelerometer data to frequency however I have set the frequency on my motor to 120hz and check with another device I am unable to FFT the accelerometer data to get the right frequency produced by the motor

Using Python 3.7, the data use is most likely correct so wondering if there is a problem in the code

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft
import numpy as np
from scipy import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# Sampling rate and time vector
start_time = 0 # seconds
end_time = 2 # seconds
sampling_rate = 6660 # Hz
N =(end_time - start_time)*sampling_rate # array size

# Nyquist Sampling Criteria
T = 1/sampling_rate # inverse of the sampling rate
x = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), int(N/2))

# FFT algorithm
yr = fft(X) # "raw" FFT with both + and - frequencies
y = 2/N * np.abs(yr[0:np.int(N/2)]) # positive freqs only

# Plotting the results
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Vibration (g)')
```

Comment: Hello. Could you explain how the oscillatory signal `X` is created ?

Comment: X is the accelerometer raw data

Comment: which look something like this                                                   
[mg] X
-56
86
356
449
146
-23
109
359
536
333
-2
-97
167
466
215
-34
61
246
592
673
-73

Comment: Have you tested your code using a theoretical pure signal such as sin(2*pi*f) ?